# How to connect your firebase database to mysql database with flutter?

Tags: mysql, firebase, flutter

I am working on a chat app that is already made as a website and trying to convert it into an application but the website is depending on mysql as it's database and I don't know how to access the database with flutter, I even tried so many ways on the internet, So anyone has ideas please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check this plugin [mysql1](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1)

> A MySQL driver for the Dart programming language. Works on Flutter and on the server.
> This library aims to provide an easy to use interface to MySQL. mysql1 originated as a fork of the SQLJocky driver.

Connect to the database

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
  host: 'localhost', 
  port: 3306,
  user: 'bob',
  password: 'wibble',
  db: 'mydb'
);
var conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
```

Execute a query with parameters:

```
var userId = 1;
var results = await conn.query('select name, email from users where id = ?', [userId]);
```

Use the results:

```
for (var row in results) {
  print('Name: ${row[0]}, email: ${row[1]}');
});
```

you can also read more from this [medium post by santosenoque](https://medium.com/@santosenoque.ss/how-to-connect-flutter-app-to-mysql-web-server-and-phpmyadmin-e100f47bfb82)

Comment: thanks for the fast responseand for this solution